# Adding a FAT Partition to a bootable USB having persistence

Tags: windows, boot, usb, partitioning

I created a Kali bootable USB using the steps mentioned in the official docs [here](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/live-usb-install-with-windows/), and then added persistence as written [here](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence/). Currently the USB is having 3 partitions, as such:[image]
(The other 1MB partition is not visible here, it's a FAT partition)

The 3.46GB partition contains Kali Linux, and the 10.95GB partition is meant to add persistence to the live USB.

I want to add another Windows-compatible partition to this drive, creating it out of the space of the 10.95GB partition. How can I do it on Windows(or from within Kali), preferably without 3rd party software?

Comment: In Windows, use diskmgmt.msc to shrink the 11 GB partition, creating free space. Then format that free space as FAT (or FAT32, which might be preferable for most uses). In Ubuntu, I'd use the *Disks* utility to do same. After each action, confirm (commit) before the next one.

Comment: Do _not_ use Disk Management to manipulate Linux partitions. They filesystem inside will be destroyed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Window's disk management wouldn't allow me to edit the partitions on the drive (The options are greyed out, most probably because of incompatibility). Also, I was unable to find "Disks" utility on My linux distribution

Comment: Use ANY tool available to your Linux distro, it doesn't matter. That said you can't do it if running from the very same USB you want to change. So you must connect it to another system.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Please see the answer I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With quite some research and the directon I got from comments I was finally able to add a FAT32 partition to the USB drive.

If you have not added persistence to your Bootable USB, let it be so as it makes easier to proceed from there.

**If you didn't yet implement the steps to add Persistence**:
First, boot into Kali linux OUTSIDE of Persistence mode, which is as good as doing it on a different system. Check the path to your USB by running `lsblk`. It is usually `/dev/sdb`, so I'll write the answer considering this is the path. Now, run `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`. Create a new partition by typing `n`. Leave everything to default values except the value of the "Last Sector": Give it a value according to your needs, preferably keep it above 4GB, but also make sure to leave some space for the other partition. This'll make `/dev/sdb3`, the partition we'll use to add persistence.

Create another partition in a similar manner, keeping everything to default values. Write `w` so that the changes are saved to the disk.

Once both the partitions are created, format both the partitions using the following commands:

```
sudo mkfs.ext3 -L persistence /dev/sdb3
sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/sdb4
```

From here continue the setup of `/dev/sdb3` as your persistent partition:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/my_usb
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/my_usb
echo "/ union" | sudo tee /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf
sudo umount /dev/sdb3
```

Reboot.

**If you added persistence**:
All the steps will remain the same, however, we will first require to delete the partition `/dev/sdb3` we created while adding persistence. Save the data if it is crucial to you, manually, since many data backup & recovery software like `apart-gtk` do not support data recovery to partitions of unequal sizes. First Unmount and Mount the partition so to make it appear in your file explorer:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb3
sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /wherever/you/want/to/mount/it
```

Once you've saved data, run fdisk (`sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`) and enter d to delete partition 3. Continue normally from here.